# cucumber Scenario Outlines: how to skip step for one scenario

Tags: rspec, cucumber, capybara

I have a strange situation where I have two examples. and I have this 
one step `fill the mandatory fields of user form` which i only need to execute for one example ("scope_self"). for other it should not run.

Is there a way to achieve this

```
Examples:
        |    action     |
        |  "scope_self" |
        |   "scope_new" |
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be an easier option to create a separate scenario with the mandatory step. Would be a cleaner implementation.

Anyways, there is a way to get this to work in the same scenario outline.

1. Split the examples table into two. Give the first table a `@Mandatory` tag which has the **one example ("scope_self")**.

> ```
>  Scenario Outline:
>       Given ............
>       When .............
>       Then .............
>
>       @Mandatory
>       Examples:
>               |    action     |
>               |  "scope_self" |
>
>       Examples:
>               |    action     |
>               |   "scope_new" |
> ```

2. Setup a variable flag and set it to false.
3. Create a tagged Before hook for the @Mandatory tag. In this set the flag variable to true.
4. In the step definition code for the mandatory option check if the flag variable is set to true or false. If true run the remaining code else skip to return.

I am basing this from Java but this should work for you in rspec...

Comment: I am against the separate scenario because there are like 10+ steps which are same. but Thanks @grasshopper solution you have below makes sense. for now plus one vote, I will accept the answer in few days if there is no other answer with better solution.

Comment: Just clarifying... The solution does not require you to split your scenario outline with the steps repeated, just divide the examples table in two for a single scenario. Have edited to make it clear...